# How to compress Image in Flutter using ImagePicker Package

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, compression

How do I compress the image taken with phone camera, using the Image Picker package in this specific scenario? It currently pops open the camera, allows a user to take a photo then it upload that photo taken to firestore, but I would like to compress the file before it is uploaded to firestore. I've seen other posts saying to utilise the 'ImageQuality' thing, but in my scenario i cannot access that, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated Im very new to flutter !

```
_selectImage(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: const Text('Create a Post'),
            children: [
              SimpleDialogOption(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: const Text('Take a photo'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();

                  Uint8List file = await pickImage(
                    ImageSource.camera,
                  );

                

                  setState(
                    () {
                      _file = file;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  void clearImage() {
    setState(() {
      _file = null;
    });
  }

void postImage(
    String uid,
    String username,
  ) async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      String res = await FirestoreMethods().uploadPost(
        _descriptionController.text,
        _file!,
        uid,
        username,
      );
      if (res == 'success') {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });

        showSnackBar(context, 'Posted!');
        clearImage();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        showSnackBar(context, res);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress

Answer (score 0):

As [Vikas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5714327/vikas) said, you could use `flutter_image_compress` to achieve that.

I'll let you a snippet that picks the image with `image_picker`, pass it to `image_cropper` so the image can be cropped, and then passed it to `flutter_image_compress` so image size can be reduced.

Hope it helps!!

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

final _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
FutureOr<File?> getGeneralImage(
  BuildContext context,
  ImageSource source, {
  CropStyle? cropStyle,
  List<CropAspectRatioPreset>? aspectRatios,
}) async {
  final pickedFile = await _imagePicker.pickImage(
    source: source,
    preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front,
  );
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    final imgCropped = await cropImage(
      File(pickedFile.path),
      uiSettings: [
        IOSUiSettings(
          title: '',
          hidesNavigationBar: true,
          showCancelConfirmationDialog: true,
          // minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
        ),
        AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          lockAspectRatio: false,
        ),
      ],
      cropStyle: cropStyle,
      aspectRatios: aspectRatios,
    );

    if (imgCropped != null) {
      return compressFile(imgCropped);
    }
  }
}

Future<File?> compressFile(File file) async {
  final filePath = file.absolute.path;

  // Create output file path
  // eg:- "Volume/VM/abcd_out.jpeg"
  final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(RegExp(r'.jp'));
  final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
  final outPath = '${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}';
  var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
    file.absolute.path,
    outPath,
    quality:
        // Add your own quality
        50,
  );
  if (result != null) {
    print(file.lengthSync());
    print(result.lengthSync());
    return result;
  }
}

FutureOr<File?> cropImage(
  File imageFile, {
  List<PlatformUiSettings>? uiSettings,
  CropStyle? cropStyle,
  List<CropAspectRatioPreset>? aspectRatios,
}) async {
  final croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
    sourcePath: imageFile.path,
    cropStyle: cropStyle ?? CropStyle.circle,
    aspectRatio: aspectRatios?.isEmpty ?? false
        ? const CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1)
        : null,
    aspectRatioPresets: aspectRatios ??
        [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        ],
    uiSettings: uiSettings,
  );
  if (croppedFile != null) {
    imageFile = File(croppedFile.path);
    return imageFile;
  }
}
```